# not able to fetch JSON Data in android Weather application

Tags: android, json, android-volley, weather

I am not able to fetch json through volley.i am getting data from open weather api.

> here is the code

i have tried to fetch the data but i am not getting response.

```
       currentTemperatureField = 
         (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
    q=bangalore,IN&appid=899bd4a7869e57cdaac65346d0659463";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new 
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    currentTemperatureField.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    try{
                        JSONObject mainJSONObject = response.getJSONObject("main");
                        String temp = mainJSONObject.getString("temp");
                        currentTemperatureField.setText(temp);
                        Log.v("WEETHER","Response: " + response.toString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you gotten any errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the response from the API, "temp" seems to return a value of type Double.

Change this line

```
String temp = mainJSONObject.getString("temp");
```

to

```
double temp = mainJSONObject.getDouble("temp");
```

And hence change the below line

```
currentTemperatureField.setText(temp);
```

to

```
currentTemperatureField.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
```